# Visual Studio Code's debugger & pipenv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pipenv, vscode-debugger

I would like to use Visual Studio Code's debugger to debug my python code, but exception occurs.
I use Windows 10, WSL, Debian, Python 3.7.6.

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'flask'
  File "/home/kazu/test/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
```

[image: ModuleNotFound]

This is python debugger console's record.

```
pyenv shell 3.7.6
/home/kazu/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/bin/python /home/kazu/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.1.58038/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 52440 /home/kazu/test/main.py 
kazu@D:~/test$ pyenv shell 3.7.6
kazu@D~/test$ /home/kazu/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/bin/python /home/kazu/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.1.58038/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 52440 /home/kazu/test/main.py
```

However, I have already installed flask using pipenv. When I don't use debugger, there isn't module error.

This is my main.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import send_file
import os
import youtube_dl

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if os.path.exists("/tmp/output.mp4"):
            os.remove("/tmp/output.mp4")
        else:
            print("Can not delete the file as it doesn't exists")
        url = request.form['url']
        ydl_opts = {'outtmpl': '/tmp/output.mp4', 'format':'bestvideo[ext=mp4]'}
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download([url])

        return send_file("/tmp/output.mp4",as_attachment=True)
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I searched the Internet and found that I should put my .venv folder in the project directory. So, I operated this command.

```
export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1
```

and now my directory structure is this.

```
.
├── main.py
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── .venv
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

However, I get same error message.

Then, I searched the Internet again and this time I set vs code's python venv path, but I got the same error message.

[image: python_venv]
Could you give me any information or suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Sincerely, Kazu

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you look in the bottom-left corner of your screen you will notice you are currently running against a pyenv install of Python and not a pipenv virtual environment. If you click on the interpreter name and select the appropriate environment where you installed flask it should fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @BrettCannon , I followed your instruction. When I clicked on the interpreter name, I had 3 choices.  `Python 2.7.16 64-bit /usr/bin/Python` and `Python 3.7.6 64-bit ./.pyenv/shims/Python` and `Python 3.7.6 64-bit (3.7.6:pyenv) ./.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/bin/python`. I tested all of them, but I got the same error message.

Comment: What is in your `.venv` directory? If that has a virtual environment you can set the path to Python in there explicitly with the `"python.pythonPath"` settting, but do make sure the virtual environment still works or else the extension will reject the setting as invalid.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, @BrettCannon . I followed your advice and `Python 3.7.6 64-bit (dialogue_aws:pipenv) ./.venv/bin/Python` choice appeared!! Now I can debug my python code. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Just want to add that `pipenv --venv` is a helpful way to find your virtual environment

Comment: Can we user pipenv and create a fixed/static virtual location , ... because I saw when we run `pipenv shell` provides some folder ending with a random value, ..... and not having a stable environment location. like VENV is performing......

Comment: @Bhuro a static location per machine isn't important to the Python extension as it will try asking Pipenv where the environment is. But otherwise Pipenv must add that extra value -- which is a hash and not random -- to tell projects apart with the same name. If consistent naming is important https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#custom-virtual-environment-location tells you how to have Pipenv use your project's own directory to store the environment.

Comment: @BrettCannon, Thanks for the reply, ... I'll check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Problem is not even the Import. 
If you have a syntax error on a file that is loaded before the same Exception is Displayed.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @BlumCore , but could you give me more concrete action, please?

Answer (score 0):

In your debbug config file `launch.json` add `"console": "integratedTerminal"`. It will first try to run virtual envs like `pypenv shell` and then run the server.

Comment: It was there by default and was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Press “Ctrl + Shift + P” to open the Command Palette and change the `Python Interpreter`

[image]

Try to change to another Python path, You may install the package in another environment.

[image]

Reference Link: https://www.alphr.com/vs-code-change-python-interpreter/